# Load Teamspeak dynamic linked library with JNI in Java

Tags: java, teamspeak

Is it possible to load the Teamspeak.so library by `System.loadLibrary` in java and access the methods declared in the .h files?
(sources are the files from the ts3_sdk_3.0.3.2 - .h files from /include/teamspeak/serverlib.h; .so files from /bin/libts3server_linux_amd64.so)

Im able to load the library:

`System.loadLibrary("ts3server_linux_amd64");` - works without error.

When i try to use a method i get a

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Testcode:

```
public class main {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ts3server_linux_amd64");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new main().onClientStartTalkingEvent();

    }

    private native void onClientStartTalkingEvent();
}
```

(.so file is stored in a lib folder and added to the classpath. OS is ubuntu).

Thanks and best regards

Comment: What's your implementation of onClientStartTalkingEvent?

Comment: The implementation looks like this:

#ifndef SERVERLIB_H
#define SERVERLIB_H

#include <teamspeak/public_definitions.h>
#include <teamspeak/server_commands.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct ServerLibFunctions {
 void (*onClientStartTalkingEvent)  (uint64 serverID, anyID clientID);
 void (*onClientStopTalkingEvent)   (uint64 serverID, anyID clientID);

(start of the serverlib.h file. I exspect it is stored in the .so library)

Comment: do i need to use something like a pointer to the methods in de .h file of the .so library? i thought the "native void" implementation is the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the teamspeak .so you need to load the .so of your JNI code (which links against the teamspeak .so).

**Edit**

To call a native library from Java you need to write a [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) wrapper. This is a native library itself which you have to load from Java and can be called through `native` functions. If the native library you want to call is C (and not C++) you can have a look at projects like [jnr-ffi](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi) or [jna](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). These allow you to call C libraries without having to write a JNI wrapper.

Comment: So ill need to write somthing like a wrapper .so

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.